# How to go about protected routes logic flow and implementation

Tags: reactjs

If I want to build a personalized app, that almost each route requires user access token, how exactly should I structure/build the app? Should I check each and every route for a access token that will call a server each time? example:

```
const ComponentName = () => {
  return (
    if (!useAccess) return <LoginComponent />
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
  );
};
```

Writing this logic in every component that need user access token(almost every route) doesn't look so good, are there any alternatives perhaps?

Or how/what should I do? Please share your approaches/best practices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [react-router-dom](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start), you can simply check if the user is authenticated or not and render the page accordingly.

```js
/// app.jsx
...
<Route path="/" component={Login} exact/>
<PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
...
```

And in private route:

```js
/// PrivateRoute.jsx

import {Route, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

export default function PrivateRoute({component: Component, ...rest}) {
    const isAuthenticated = true // true/false get data from state, context anywhere
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            isAuthenticated ? (
                <Component {...props}/>
            ) : (
                <Redirect to="/login"/>
            )
        )}
        />
    )
}
```